# @ResponseStatus annotated class that extends RuntimeException, overrides exception message

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, error-handling

While playing with code, I created a custom exception `LackOfBasicRecordsInDatabase` and a constructor to pass a basic info-message. The issue is when I throw this exception and original string is null at the end of response.
Here is the code:

```java
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE)
public class LackOfBasicRecordsInDatabase extends RuntimeException{
    public LackOfBasicRecordsInDatabase(String message){
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Place where I throw error

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity someMethod() {
    if(...) throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE, "message");
    if(...) throw new LackOfBasicRecordsInDatabase("pls pass this message");
    ...
    }
```

ErrorController:

```
@RestController
public class MyErrorController implements ErrorController {

    @RequestMapping("error")
    public String handleError(Exception ex, HttpServletRequest request) {
        String errorMessagePrefix = "Congrats, You encountered ";
        Object status = request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_STATUS_CODE);
        String appendix = "some error";
        if (status != null) {
            appendix = status.toString();
        }
        return errorMessagePrefix + appendix + " " + request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_MESSAGE).toString();
    }
}
```

There is also `server.error.include-message=always` in `application.properties`.

The response of `ResponseStatusException` with `ErrorController`:

```
Congrats, You encountered 507 message
```

The response of `LackOfBasicRecordsInDatabase` with `ErrorController`:

```
Congrats, You encountered 507
```

The response of `LackOfBasicRecordsInDatabase` without `ErrorController`:

```
{
    "timestamp": "...",
    "status": 507,
    "error": "Insufficient Storage",
    "message": "pls pass this message",
    "path": "/somepath"
}
```

So we see that `ResponseStatusException` message is passed correctly to `ErrorController`,
and `LackOfBasicRecordsInDatabase` message is not.
What to do if I want to use `LackOfBasicRecordsInDatabase` class and pass it's message?
When it is better to use  `ResponseStatusException` and when the custom one?

Comment: I got error: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Throwable.getMessage()" because the return value of "jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getAttribute(String)" is null